# Elasticsearch aggregation with nesting and reverse nesting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Let's assume a collection of docs like the following:

```
{
    "product_id": "11111111-0000-0000-0000-111111111111",
    "product_name": "Product A",
    "date": "2020-11-25",
    "sold_in_countries": [
      {
        "name": "Country A",
        "count": 100
      },
      {
        "name": "Country B",
        "count": 200
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to list:
For each country, what are the top 5 products sold (based on sum of corresponding "count" within the country object.

As "name", "count" are within the nested object, we would need a nested aggregation. But then "product_name" is not, hence we need "reverse_nested". I ended up with:

```
"aggs": {
    "country_name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sold_in_countries"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "country_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sold_in_countries.name",
            "size": 5,
            "order": {
              "sale_count": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sale_count": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "sold_in_countries.count"
              } 
            },
            "product_name": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "product_name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "product_name.keyword",
                    "order": {
                      "sale_count": "desc"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "sale_count": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "sold_in_countries"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "sale_count": {
                          "sum": {
                            "field": "sold_in_countries.count"
                          }  
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Issue: While the first aggregation with country_name considers correct "sale_count" (100 for Country A and 200 for Country B), the second aggregation by product_name considers "sale_count" that is the sum of all "count" in the country objects (300). How to go about it?